# arch - installing systemd-boot : hanging after writing random seed

Tags: systemd, boot

Installing arch to a single boot system previously occupied by Ubuntu, using https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide.

No obvious issues and am now at the bootloader section. I want to try systemd-boot.

Following instructions at

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-boot

- Partitions are mounted.

Have run

```
#arch-chroot /mnt
```

`bootctl install` runs without error that I can see. I can't copy paste from the installer but this following is what's happening with `...` to show where lines I've not typed.

```
#bootctl install
 Created "/efi/efi/EFI"
 Created ...
 Created ...
  ...
 Copied /usr/lib/systemd/boot/efi/systemd-bootx64.efi" to "/boot/efi/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi"
  ...
  Created "/boot/efi/bc....."
  Random seed file /boot/efi/loader/random-seed successfully written (512 bytes).
```

The system seems to be stalled at this point. The terminal prompt has not come back. (30+ minutes)

Cannot Ctl-C out.